# How can I order a list of class based on a value of each class?

Tags: c#, list, class

I have this class :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

and I add 3 of this class on a List :

```
MyClass class1 = new MyClass()
MyClass class2 = new MyClass()
MyClass class3 = new MyClass()

IList<MyClass> classList = new List<MyClass>().ToList();
classList.Add(class1);
classList.Add(class2);
classList.Add(class3);
```

Now, I'd like to order this list (ascending) according to the `MyClass.value` value.
How can I do it on C#?

IList is not mandatory, so if you know any other strategies to order this would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this after you add all items to classList. ( This works in Framwork 3.5sp1 or later)

```
classList = classList.OrderBy(cc => cc.value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ and the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method:

```
var sortedList = classList.OrderBy(i => i.value);
```

There is a corresponding [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You will call

```
classList.Sort()
```

but before you have to implement IComparable interface like that

```
 class MyClass: IComparable
{

    public int value { get; set; }

    #region IComparable Members

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        MyClass e = (MyClass)obj;
        int r;
        r = this.value.CompareTo(e.value);
        return r;

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var orderedList = classList.Orderby(x =>x.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with LINQ, something like:

```
from cl in classList 
orderby cl.value
select cl;
```